# Laravel 8 prefix to current route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

```
Route::middleware(['auth', 'admin'])->prefix('admin')->group(function () {
   Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\Admin\IndexController::class, 'index']);
});
```

and when I go to this url http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/

it shows error: The requested resource /admin/ was not found on this server.

[image]

Comment: That looks like a webserver error instead of a Laravel routing Not Found issue. You can verify your routes by using `php artisan route:list` on the command line to verify your route is correct, but you might need to make sure that the route is actually hitting Laravel by checking your web server config

Comment: Can you access http://127.0.0.1:8000?  Share the error screenshot please

Answer (score 0):

Try using below approach:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => ['auth', 'admin']], function(){
    Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\Admin\IndexController::class, 'index']);
});
```

Comment: Try running `php artisan cache:clear` , `php artisan config:clear` & `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: the page display this text: The requested resource /admin/ was not found on this server.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Route::middleware(['auth', 'admin'])->prefix('admin')->group(function () {
    Route::get('',  'IndexController@index');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please look inside your Public folder. You probably created a folder called 'admin'. Rename that into something else or remove it if you're not using it.